# How to use accordion in Magento-2

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7

How to use accordion for FAQ in Magento-2.In which file is suitable for this.If Anyone knows please explain me?

Comment: You don't even need to code. Just create a new page on Content->Pages->Add New Page, then paste the code on the Content section, save it and finish.

Answer (score 2):

M2 provides accordion as a widget out of the box. You can use it in your template file or in CMS page.

**/{magento_root}/app/code/{NameSpace}/{Module}/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml**

There are two ways to use an accordion widget.

> Initialize accordion in JS components

```
<div id="element">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 1</div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 2</div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 3</div>
</div>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'accordion'], function ($) {
        $("#element").accordion();
    });
</script>
```

> Initialize accordion in a template

```
    <div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 1</div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 2</div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Kindly refer this [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html) for more details.